# File Handling in c not producing the required result

Tags: c

I am new to file handling, when I tried to read data from keypad to file and output the contents of that file on the screen I am not getting the desired result with the code below

```
/* get data from the keyboared till the end of file and write it to the 
file named "input" agian read the data from this file on to the screen*/

#include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   { 
     FILE *fp;
     char c;
     printf("enter the data from the keyboared\n");

     fp=fopen("input.txt","w");

     while((c=getchar()!=EOF))
     {
       putc(c,fp);
     }

     fclose(fp);

     printf("reading the data from the file named input\n");

     fopen("input.txt","r");

     while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
     {
       printf("%c",c);
     }

     fclose(fp);

     return 0;

  }
```

I am getting output something like this h ?

Also is there a way so that i can find out where on the harddisk this file is created?

Comment: Although it's not difficult to try for ourselves, if you're talking about unexpected/undesired results, it's usually useful to post what you expect and what you get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, this is wrong because of precedence.

> ```
> while((c=getchar()!=EOF))
>                        ^
> ```

Instead of storing the character, you will continuously store the comparison between the character and `EOF`. So you will continuously store a long line of `1`.

Try this:

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
                  ^
```

Second `getc` and `getchar` return `int`. [So **`ch` should be `int`**, not `char`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html). Using a `char` could mean the loop will never terminate on some systems.

Comment: can you tell me  is there a way so that i can find out where on the harddisk this file is created?

Comment: @haris In the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
fopen("input.txt","r");
```

Is obviously wrong. Seems you want:

```
fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
```

Instead.

Comment: yes u are wright..but it worked without fp as well.i am wondering how?

Comment: @haris: by coincidence. The pointer returned by the second call to fopen was the same as the one returned by the first. That's not very likely to happen again if you expand the program, or try to run it on a different compiler.